# Define style classes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to plot different curves in one matplotlib figure. Each curve must have its own style (color, thickness, etc..) and I would like to set the styles in one matplotlibrc file. I would like to use a name like line1, line2, etc.. to refer to different styles, and not to a color cycle. Is this possible in motplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matplotlib rc file is meant to provide the default style for a plot, its not meant to provide styles in the way of Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) or classes.

So what is possible, is to create several rc files and use them in a context, as explained in the [temporary-styling](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#temporary-styling) part of the customizing tutorial, e.g. using a file called `line1.mplstyle` you could do

```
with plt.style.context(('line1')):
    plt.plot([1,2,3])
```

Because this seems to be a little overkill for just setting some line properties, it might be sufficient to simply create some argument dictionaries to provide to the plot command, like so:

```
line1 = dict(lw=2, ls=":", color="red")
line2 = dict(lw=0.8, ls="-", color="blue")

ax.plot([1,2,3], **line1)
ax.plot([1,2,3], **line2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`cycler()` can be used to set cycles for `linewidth`, `linestyle`, etc. as well as `color`. The length of the list of each argument must be the same. The list of available properties is defined [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b09aad279b5dcfc49dcf43e0b064eee664ddaf68/lib/matplotlib/rcsetup.py#L585-L604).

```py
# series 1: color=red, linewidth=1, linestyle='-'
# series 2: color=blue, linewidth=2, linestyle='--'
axes.prop_cycle: cycler(color=['red', 'blue'], linewidth=[1, 2], linestyle=['-', '--'])
```